# AngularJs - how to support a textbox with hyperlinks

Tags: html, css, angularjs, textarea

I'm new to Angular but I'm trying to implement a textbox that allows users to enter in links.  I only want to support links, and otherwise I want to block all html from being presented as such.  I could theoretically use something other than a textarea, but my requirements are that it must be bound to a variable in my scope (right now with ng-model) and I cannot accept html tags other than '< a >'

Here is my example [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/XyJs1GFBkObzzaiSAWr7?p=preview)

In the example, I would like the second seeded item to display as a link, blue and underlined.  However, the third item should display as it is currently shown (without interpreting it as html).

HTML:

```
<textarea maxlength="160" ng-model="val.text"></textarea>
<div class="btn" ng-click="submit()">Submit</div>
<br><br>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{display(item)}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.submit = function() {
  if (!$scope.val.text) return
  $scope.items.push($scope.val.text);
}
$scope.display = function(txt) {
  return txt; 
  // something here?  if txt contains <a> and </a> indicate 
  // that we should display as html
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into `contenteditable`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable

Comment: Does it give me the ability to limit it to links only?  Do you have any working examples?  This one on their site doesn't seem to have what I need.. http://html5demos.com/contenteditable